Overlapping Regions
In Lightning App Builder I created a new Lightning page with Header and Three Regions.
In Header I put my header component, in the left Region I put my left component[width=420px], in the middle Region I put my middle component[width=1000px], and in the right Region I put my right component[width=540px].
The issue is that the middle component is overlapping the right component. Could you help me resolve this problem?
